"anderer Meinung" und "einer anderen Meinung"
Ich bin einer anderen Meinung.
Ich bin anderer Meinung.
Warum ist im ersten Fall der Genitiv "anderen", und im zweiten Fall "anderer"?

Die Flexion eines Adjektivs variiert mit dem Artikel. Der Absatz von Grammis bringt das auf den Punkt:

Ein flektiertes Adjektiv kann eine der fünf folgenden Endungen haben: -e, -en, -er, -es, -em. Wenn vor einem Adjektiv ein Artikelwort mit Endung steht, dann flektiert es schwach, also mit -e oder -en. Ansonsten flektieren Adjektive stark.
Oder kurz: Stark, wenn nötig. Sonst schwach.

Die Notwendigkeit ergibt sich daraus, den Fall deutlich zu machen. Wenn das der Artikel schon übernommen hat, muss es das Adjektiv nicht mehr leisten.

Vielen Dank, der Artikel auf Grammis ist hilfreich. Ich hatte so etwas in der Art schon vermutet, aber nichts dazu auf duden.de gefunden. Du kennst nicht zufällig eine offizielle Quelle, wo dieser Fall beschrieben wird?

Ich glaube nicht, dass man eine verbindlichere Auskunft findet, oder dass es überhaupt ein Grammatik-Werk gibt, das einen offiziellen Stempel hat (vergleichbar mit dem Duden einst für  Rechtschreibung), lasse mich aber gerne belehren.

Adjektive (und Adverbien) haben zwei verschiedene Deklinationssysteme, die je nach Bedarf angewendet werden. Außerdem können dieselben Worte, von wenigen Ausnahmen abgesehen, als Adjektiv und als Adverb gebraucht werden:

ein leuchtendes rotes Auto
ein leuchtend rotes Auto

beides ist möglich, hat aber eine andere Bdeutung: im ersten Fall leuchtet das (rote) Auto, im zweiten Fall das "rot". "leuchtend" ist hier kein Adjektiv wie im ersten Fall, sondern die nähere Bestimmung eines Adjektivs, deshalb ein Adverb.
Zum Wechsel von starker zu schwacher Deklination:

der rote Schrank
ein roter Schrank
roter Schrank

Das ist in beiden Fällen ein Nominativ (Antwort auf die Frage "wer?"), aber beim bestimmten Artikel wird die schwache, beim unbestimmten die starke Beugung verwendet.
Genau das ist bei "anderen" auch der Fall. Je nachdem, ob ein unbestimmter, bestimmter oder vielleicht gar kein Artikel verwendet wird, wechselt die verwendete Deklination.
Nachbemerkung:
Der Grund, warum Adjektive und Substantive überhaupt eine gemeinsame Deklination haben, ist ein Erbe der indogermanischen Ursprache, die zunächst zwischen Substantiven und Adjektiven nicht unterschied. Man hatte keinen "guten Freund", sondern "einen Freund, einen guten".

Alles korrekt, aber das erklärt nur den Unterschied zwischen bestimmtem und unbestimmten Fall, und der Verwendung von Adverben; beides hat jetzt nichts mit meiner Frage zu tun.

@user1934428: "einer anderen" = unbestimmter Artikel, "anderer" = kein (genauer: Null-)Artikel, deshalb der Unterschied starke <-> schwache Flexion.

Das ist klar, aber mir hatte nur in Deiner Antwort das Beispiel mit dem Nullartikel gefehlt. Genau der Nullartikel ist ja, wie guidot schön erklärt hat,  in meinem Problem den Unterschied aus.

@user1934428: der fehlte, weil zwischen Nullartikel und unbestimmtem Artikel kein Unterschied besteht. Wie auch immer, ich habe ihn für Sie nachgetragen.
